# Java PropertyUtils.getProperty throws no getter method in class

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils

As you can see I clearly have a getter for property 'name' in class TemplateVars. A similar piece of code works elsewhere in the system. So why is the following code throwing the following exception?

**Code**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException {
        String template = "Hello. My name is %%name%% %%surname%% %%contact.email%%";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("%%(.*?)%%");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(template);

        TemplateVars item = new TemplateVars();

        while (matcher.find()) {
            String placeHolder = matcher.group(1);
            String value;

            if(placeHolder.contains(".")){
                value = PropertyUtils.getNestedProperty(item, placeHolder).toString();
            }else{
                value = PropertyUtils.getProperty(item,placeHolder).toString();
            }
            template = template.replace("%%" + placeHolder + "%%", value);
        }

        System.out.println(template);
    }

}

class TemplateVars {
    private String name = "Boo";
    private String surname = "Foo";
    private Contact contact;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public Contact getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public void setContact(Contact contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }
}

class Contact {
    private String email = "boo.foo@mail.com";

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

**Exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Property 'name' has no getter method in class 'class TemplateVars'
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getSimpleProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1274)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getNestedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:808)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:884)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getProperty(PropertyUtils.java:464)
    at Main.main(Main.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

The piece of code that I have posted above is only to serve as proof of concept.

Comment: For a proof of concept, go for a REAL [mcve]: A) no content that is not required (like that pattern matching there) and B) something that can easily be compiled and executed.

Comment: @GhostCat As far as I can tell this *is* an MCVE.

Comment: It is for sure not minimal. Again: what has the pattern matching to do with that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is simply because your classes `TemplateVars` and `Contact` have the package-local access modifier and `PropertyUtils` can not gain access to them.

To solve it make them top classes (i.e. public), or public static inner classes of `Main` class.

Comment: Turns out even a static inner class is required to be public. I couldn't find a documentation for this behavior

Comment: @defaultlocale sure, I meant it but forgot to mention. Thank you, I've updated

Comment: in my case i am having class with public access modifier then also i got this error

Comment: Thank you so much @Andremoniy. It took me a while to get here but you saved my day.